# flow typing react/redux Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import type { Store } from 'redux';

import configureStore from './configureStore';

export const store: Store<*, *> = configureStore();

function CustomProvider(children: React.Node) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}

export default CustomProvider;
```

I have this flow-erorr:

> [flow] React element `Provider` (This type is incompatible with)

What type i am need to use for Provider?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `flow` do you use?
I just created a new empty project and added your code to my `App.js` and `flow` doesn't complain.
I used `flow-bin ^0.56.0` in my `package.json`.

Comment: hmm. Same version. What IDE you are use?

Comment: @Daxik I'm using `WebStorm 2017.2.4`, but that shouldn't be the problem, since I just run `flow` via CI